# Importing External Jars in GWT Projects

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I have an external Jar ,

- which is in the Project BuildPath
- which is in the WEB-INF/lib folder

and Eclipse has no problem identifying the file.

But GWT complains  by saing that the source code is not available.

```
[ERROR] Line 8: No source code is available for type javax.ws.rs.core.Application; 
did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Do I have to explicitly tell it inherit it? But This is not a module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Classpath:**

Try placing the Jar into your \war\WEB_INF\lib\ folder so that it is packaged into the WAR and is available at runtime.

It should also be on your project buildpath as a library.

### **Other:**

It seems your external jar is the JAX-RS jar? You may find the following <[link](http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features)> helpful:
(under the *"Deploying a RESTful Web service"* heading)

This seems to indicate that you will have to modify the web.xml despite JAX-RS not being a GWT module.

Comment: I have the jar in the lib folder too but I get the same error.

Comment: I realized that I had it in the client side. I moved it to the server side.

Answer (score 0):

GWT is **compiler**, it ignores binary code in jar. Only source code matters. Some jars are packaged with source code, others are not. It seems you have a latter case here. Find a source code and create/repackage a jar.